# "it seems incorrect for me" vs "it seems to be incorrect for me"

Tags: be

Would it be correct if I said "it seems incorrect for me"?
Should I prefer the following form "it seems to be incorrect for me".

Comment: They are both correct but imply slightly different meanings. It really depends more on the context.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 "slightly different meanings" what is the difference?

Comment: it depends on the context, but they don't really mean anything different, just that they create a different feeling. The `to be` one is more connected to the object that is seeming incorrect while the other is more connected to the `me`.

Comment: FYI, according to Google search, "incorrect to me" is about two thousand times more common phrasing than "incorrect for me"

Comment: Prepositions are little words with many meanings, overlapping, setting and context dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various possible contexts here which call for different treatments.

***It seems incorrect to me that 2 + 2 equals 5.*** *For* would be entirely inappropriate in this example.

***It seems incorrect for me, a distant relative, to comment on the upbringing of their children.***  *For* is perfectly proper in this instance.

In either of these two instances one could add *to be* after seems and it would make no difference to the meaning